# How to use json normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am using the below code to parse JSON data to CSV from rest API, but there are some nested objects which I need in different columns, I have tried using JSON normalize but couldn't get through. can anyone please advise?

```
import requests
import json, pandas as pd
import csv
import urllib

URL = "https://dsv.ihsmvals.com/holidays/v1.0/symbol/FX-GBP/startDate/20210101/endDate/20211231"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

print(response)
text = response.read()
json_data = json.loads(text)

print(json_data)
df = pd.read_json(URL)
bn = pd.DataFrame(df.events.values.tolist())
pd.json_normalize(bn).head()
bn.to_csv("output.csv")
```

This is how the output looks
[image]

This is how it should be
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify the `record_path`:

```
bn = pd.json_normalize(bn)
bn.join(pd.json_normalize(bn.pop('events'))).head()
```

Comment: df=pd.json_normalize(json_data,'events') this worked but it it now only saving events column in csv

Comment: @Naina `bn.join(pd.json_normalize(bn.pop('events'))).head()`

Comment: what is bn here

Comment: @Naina `bn = pd.json_normalize(bn)`

Comment: bn=pd.json_normalize(bn)
NameError: name 'bn' is not defined